# Opengl window closes by itself

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I was trying out this OpenGL program of displaying a triangle. It executes the program successfully , gives an output window with a triangle drawn, but the window closes itself after 2-3 of showing the output. Is it supposed to happen or am I doing something wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;

    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);
    
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

And on the output screen I am getting as:
(process 30696) exited with code -1073741819.

On debugging, found out that it throws an error on the line glSwapBuffers(window), with the call stack:
igxelpicd32.dll!79361319()  Unknown

But the OpenGL window doesn't close on commenting the glDrawArrays() function line

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you targeting? Using `glVertexAttribPointer` usually requires you to use your own shaders.

Comment: Version: 4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.4575 I still havent added the shader part though, its using the system in built ones

Comment: As a precaution, remove the glWindowShouldClose(window) and just use a while True loop. Does this changes anything

Comment: I removed glWindowShouldClose(window)...but still didn't change anything, The window still closing itself after a while

Comment: Can you show what command you use to compile?

Comment: I am coding on Visual Studio, so I just click on the compile button

Comment: I run your code on my machine, also with 4.6; The window doesn't close unless I click the close button. My machine is Windows 11 with an NVIDIA card. Also works on my intel onboard chip.

Comment: @Nemizis the command should be visible in the debug window / panel at the bottom, If you can't find it, can you show / report the configuration you used for the project?

Comment: I am running on an Intel Graphics, so is that the issue?

Comment: I am running on intel integrated graphics too, that should not be the issue

Comment: ¿Doesn't Visual Studio debugger show any more info on the error? Error code is an  access violation, hard crash that is. So debugger should typically break and show a stack trace. Also if you target 4.6 then you should not rely on presence of fixed-function pipeline remains and instead use shaders properly.

Comment: The debugger doesn't show anything more than: D:\OpenGL\Opengl\Debug\Opengl.exe (process 17252) exited with code -1073741819....

Comment: Also now my screen has started flickering since I executed this program, does it got to anything with this

Comment: ¿Do you even use the debugger and not just launch program by double clicking an .exe? ¿What happens if you execute this program line by line? ¿Which line will trigger the crash?

Comment: Given the error code and the the screen flicker it might be that your driver has been corrupted or something equally fatal has happened. It reboot just to be safe

Comment: Okay...now that i executed it line by line...there was an exception thrown on line glfwSwapBuffers(window)...

Comment: ¿And what does the call stack look like? (it would be a good idea to add it into the question).

Comment: The call stack is:   igxelpicd32.dll!79361319() Unknown